# The set of chen prime numbers

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, analytic-number-theory

Let $P$ be the set of prime numbers and $P_c$ be the set of chen prime numbers.

What is the upper density of $P_c$ with relative to $P$ ? If the answer is $>0$ then the result in Zhou, Binbin (2009). "The Chen primes contain arbitrarily long arithmetic progressions". Acta Arith. 138 (4): 301–315 is a special case of Green - Tao theorem.

Comment: A prime $p$ is a Chen prime if $p+2$ is prime or a square of prime or the product of two primes. What result do you know on their generating function, density..

Comment: @reuns , the set of chen prime numbers is a subset of the set of prime numbers, using green - tao we might be able to deduce the result in the previous research paper easily